# delaying signal

Tags: fourier-analysis

What does delaying a signal mean? Graphically? Mathematically? Is it, advancing to the next numbers, or using the previous numbers? Suppose i have $x[n] = \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ and i use $x[n-m]$ (example $x[n-3]$, what actually happens behind the scenes)?  I can't get the gist and main concept behind.. thanks . Lesson: z transforms, laplace, transforms.

Our topic deals with z transforms and an introductory to dsp.

Comment: Delay means previous samples, samples, samples. Think echo, echo, echo.

Comment: lets say x[n] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] then what whould x[n-3] look like?

Answer (score 1):

It's confusing if you write $x[n] = [0,1,2,\ldots]$, so don't do that.

What you really mean is that
$$\begin{align}
x(0) &= 0, \\
x(1) &= 1, \\
x(2) &= 2, \\
\end{align}$$
and so on. Then it is easy to see that if you have a signal $y$ such that $y(n) = x(n-3)$, then
$$\begin{align}
y(3) &= x(3-3) = x(0) = 0, \\
y(4) &= 1, \\
y(5) &= 2, \\
\end{align}$$
and so on.